# jquery - toggle animate (almost there?)

Tags: jquery, navigation, jquery-animate, toggle

I've looked around at how to toggle animate in jquery, but still no luck.. this is what I have, any help would be great.

I have a vertical sidebar that when you click a button (a.mobile-menu-icon) the div slides 250px to the right. I then want it to slide back (-250px;) again when you click the same button.

```
$('click', 'a.mobile-menu-icon').toggle(function(){
    $('#sidebar').animate({
        left: '0px;'
        }, 500);
    }, 
    function(){
        $('#sidebar').animate({
            left: '-250px;'
            }, 500);
    });
```

Comment: Toggle is deprecated in jquery 1.8 and removed in 1.9 : http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be if jquery < 1.9

```
$('a.mobile-menu-icon').toggle(function(){
    $('#sidebar').animate({
        left: '0px;'
    }, 500);
}, function(){
    $('#sidebar').animate({
        left: '-250px;'
    }, 500);
});
```

In 1.9 this particular usage of toggle is removed